Troubleshooting for robot_blockly
I'm working with repo https://github.com/erlerobot/robot_blockly/tree/master?tab=readme-ov-file
After running roslaunch robot_blockly robot_blockly.launch I get the following output:
... logging to /home/user/.ros/log/ca68e98c-a5ce-11ef-a7d3-854d1c17ced4/roslaunch-user-49163.log

Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.

Press Ctrl-C to interrupt

Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.



started roslaunch server http://user:43779/



SUMMARY

========



PARAMETERS

 * /rosdistro: noetic

 * /rosversion: 1.17.0



NODES

  /

    robot_blockly_backend (robot_blockly/robot_blockly_backend.py)

    robot_blockly_webserver (robot_blockly/pywebserver.py)



ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311



process[robot_blockly_backend-1]: started with pid [49258]

process[robot_blockly_webserver-2]: started with pid [49261]

When I open the following web page: http://user:1036/pages/blockly.html# where the 'Launch' button is I see the 'Server is down'.
What could be causing the error: wrong port, wrong browser permissions, or broken connection between frontend and backend?
